# How to combine an AngularJS component and directive to enable compilation?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-1.5

I need to refresh one HTML element at certain times. The element is currently generated by a component. I've managed to add a directive (the Attributes example at [AngularJS Reference / $compile](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.11/docs/api/ng/service/$compile)) to my custom module, but I don't know how to link the two together so that I can trigger the directive to compile from the component.

I could either nest the component inside the directive, or the directive inside the component with the element inside the directive. But I still don't know how to trigger the directive to compile from the component.

Comment: very unclear what you need, some code with explanation what does not work may help

Comment: @PetrAveryanov I've created a Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/paAbMtC3KkARsBoM?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1 Unfortunately, it's stopped working.